# Python subprocess.call() not working with >> operator

Tags: subprocess

I'm trying to write a program that automatically sets up python shell scripts for me.  Heres the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import click
import subprocess

@click.command()
@click.argument('name')

def foo(name):
    subprocess.call("cd ~/bin", shell=True)
    subprocess.call(["touch", name])
    subprocess.call(["echo", "'#!/usr/bin/env python3'", ">>", name])
    subprocess.call(["chmod", "+x", name])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

When it runs this is the output I get:

```
'#!/usr/bin/env python3' >> foo
```

Comment: You are looking for file objects and the `os.chmod` call.  `subprocess.call` is distinctly the wrong way to do this.

Comment: you need `shell=True` for the call with redirection. The `cd` will not work, as the currnent working dir is restored after the subprocess ends.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to approach this problem is to use the built-in Python libraries for creating files so that you can catch the exceptions easier. I've made a simple outline for you, but you should add some error checking.

```py
import click
import os
import stat

@click.command()
@click.argument('name')

def foo(name):
    file_to_create = os.path.expanduser("~/bin/") + name
    with open(file_to_create, 'w') as file:
        file.write("#!/usr/bin/env python3\n")
    file_stats = os.stat(file_to_create)
    os.chmod(file_to_create, file_stats.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC) # equivalent of 'chmod +x'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```